# how to check checkbox on website(intranet) using VBA code but i can not find html source of it

Tags: html, vba

[image]

Hi to all coding masters.

I want to check checkbox on intranet website using vba code, basically i can code vba to check checkbox on website, but this case i have no idea how to do because i can not search html source of the checkbox in DOM.

As the picture, first input model name on the blank number 1 and second, click Search button.
then it searches and shows model information as the picture.

So, I coded to do number1 and number2 process automatically.

and Number 3 is problem for me.

when i hit mouse right click on number 3 spot to see html source, it checks checkbox.
So i was trying to find source in DOM after ctrl + shift + I to find each structure.
but even using ctrl + shift + I in DOM, there is no source of the checkbox.

Do i something wrong..?

additionally, i attache picture when click ctrl + shift + I version in DOM.
[image]

I can access every html source on blue color zone except not blue color zone.
and the checkbox (number 3) is not on blue color zone i guess.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe it's in an iframe? If you do not include a link or the source code here, then no one is going to know either.

Comment: braX, Thanks. It's too long source. i think that no blue color zone is in javascript. though.